# Update Entire column in a data frame with Values of another values based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, merge

I have two dataframes, I wish to combine the unique values and update a column value alone of the existing record instead of adding new record.

```
DF1<-data.frame(name = c("Test1","Test2","Test3"),
                Value = c(10,20,30),
                Remarks = c("Good","Best","Perfect")
)
```

```
DF2<- data.frame(name = c("Test","Test2","Test3","Test4"),
                 Value = c(10,22,30, 40),
                 Remarks = c("Good","Best","Perfect","NEW"))
```

I have attempted

```
DF3 <- unique(bind_rows(x = DF1, y = DF2))
```

The result is

```
   name Value Remarks
1 Test1    10    Good
2 Test2    20    Best
3 Test3    30 Perfect
4  Test    10    Good
5 Test2    22    Best
7 Test4    40     NEW
```

But I desire to achieve

```
   name Value Remarks
1 Test1    10    Good
2 Test2    **22**    Best
3 Test3    30 Perfect
4  Test    10    Good
5 Test4    40     NEW
```

For Exisiting values instead of adding new records, I wish to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `rows_upsert`

```
library(dplyr)
rows_upsert(DF1, DF2)
```

-output

```
   name Value Remarks
1 Test1    10    Good
2 Test2    22    Best
3 Test3    30 Perfect
4  Test    10    Good
5 Test4    40     NEW
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

DF1<-data.frame( name= c("Test1","Test2","Test3"),
                 Value=c(10,20,30),
                 Remarks =c("Good","Best","Perfect")
)

DF2<- data.frame( name= c("Test","Test2","Test3","Test4"),
                  Value=c(10,22,30, 40),
                  Remarks =c("Good","Best","Perfect","NEW"))

right_join(DF1, DF2) %>% 
  bind_rows(DF1 %>% filter(!name %in% DF2$name)) %>% 
  arrange(name)
#> Joining, by = c("name", "Value", "Remarks")
#>    name Value Remarks
#> 1  Test    10    Good
#> 2 Test1    10    Good
#> 3 Test2    22    Best
#> 4 Test3    30 Perfect
#> 5 Test4    40     NEW
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I cannnot use Filter here as the Remark' column of DF1 has to be retained, I just want the Value column to be updated and add new records in DF2 to DF1, Sorry I missed to menion it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `powerjoin`, which can handle conflicted columns when joining.

```r
library(powerjoin)

power_full_join(DF1, DF2, by = "name", conflict = coalesce_yx)

#    name Value Remarks
# 1 Test1    10    Good
# 2 Test2    22    Best
# 3 Test3    30 Perfect
# 4  Test    10    Good
# 5 Test4    40     NEW
```

- `conflict = coalesce_xy`: Columns from the first data are prior to those from the second data when conflicting.
- `conflict = coalesce_yx`: Columns from the second data are prior to those from the first data when conflicting.

Comment: Thanks for introducing powerjoin, it has some wonderful features. I will explore it.

Comment: Following code solves my purpose :                       power_full_join(df1, df2, by = "name", conflict = rw ~ ifelse(is.na(.y),.x,.y))

Comment: @Lakshmikanth I think `~ ifelse(is.na(.y), .x, .y)` does the same thing as `coalesce_yx`. If you find some places where the both functions get different outputs, please let me know. I also think `rw` is not needed because `ifelse` is a vectorized function.